# Creating of Server on Node is not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a http listener using node js.

Using express framework to create a controller and http module to create a server .

I have following code written to .js File ,but when I execute using node  , 
not getting any response.

I have saved http and express module using `npm install <ModuleName> --save`.

But when I navigate to `localhost:3000/` not getting any response back.

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/",function(req,res){

    res.send("<html><body><h1>Express</h1></body></html>");
});

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Basic but some times we may miss it. 1)Is node_module directory available in project directory? 2)Add a console.log below server.listen(3000) to see line got executed or not. I just run your script its working for me.

Comment: Your code works for me as-is, after npm init, npm install express --save, and then node index.js (with your script being index.js on my box).  Make sure your firewall isnt' blocking port 3000 for local requests.

Answer (score 0):

convert your code to

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/",function(req,res){

    res.send("<html><body><h1>Express</h1></body></html>");
});


app.listen(3000);
```

create your server using exoress. It is working